# javascript autoupdate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mouse

I'd like to do the following;

1. create a 2 -column array of arbitrary finite length (say, 10 rows)
2. populate it sequentially from a constant-rate datastream
3. once its populated, update it from the same datastream ( ie replace element 0, move 1-9 down, discard old 9)
4. (optimally) output an average for each column

I can probably do 4 myself, but have no idea how to do 1-3.

If it helps, I'm trying to translate this;

http://kindohm.com/2011/03/01/KinectCursorControl.html (see under the dreaded shaking cursor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work ok (nice question, by the way - fun little challenge, since there are tons of ways to do it)

```
var pointSmoother = (function(){
  var pointCount     = 10, // number of points to keep
      componentCount = 2,  // number of components per point (i.e. 2 for x and y)
      points = [];

  function clear() {
    var i, l;
    for( i = 0, l = componentCount ; i < l ; i++ ) {
      if( typeof points[i] === 'undefined' ) {
        points.push([]);
      } else {
        points[i].splice(0, pointCount);
      }
    }
  }

  clear();

  function pushPoint( /* point components */ ) {
    var i, l;
    for( i = 0 ; i < componentCount ; i++ ) {
      points[i].unshift(arguments[i]);
      points[i] = points[i].slice(0, pointCount);
    }
  }

  function average() {
    var i, j, l, sum, averages = [];
    l = points[0].length;
    for( i = 0 ; i < componentCount ; i++ ) {
      sum = 0;
      for( j = 0 ; j < l ; j++ ) {
        sum += points[i][j];
      }
      averages.push(sum/l);
    }
    return averages;
  }

  function getPoints() {
    return points;
  }

  return {
      getPoints: getPoints,
      pushPoint: pushPoint,
      clear:     clear,
      average:   average
  };
}());
```

What it basically does is it creates an object and assigns it to `pointSmoother`. The object has 4 methods: `pushPoint()`, `clear()`, `getPoints()` and `average()`. At the top of the thing you can set how many coordinates a point has, and how many points (maximum) to keep. I used your example of 2 coordinates per point, and 10 points at a time.

Now, I've made the assumption that you get your values in sets of 2 at a time. Let's call those 2 values `x` and `y`. When you receive them, add them to the thing by using `pointSmoother.pushPoint(x, y);`. You can then get the "average point", by calling `pointSmoother.average()` which will return an array with (in this case) 2 values: average x and average y.

If you want to look at the array yourself, you can call `pointSmoother.getPoints()` which will return the points array. And lastly, `pointSmoother.clear()` will empty the array of previous values.

Here's a demo, of sorts: http://jsfiddle.net/tapqs/1/

Comment: The *clear* function really should clear the points array (e.g. set its length to zero), not just assign a new array to *points* since if a reference has been kept to the array elsewhere, that array will remain unchanged.

Comment: @RobG: True, I'll update my answer. I only added the `getPoints` function at the last minute, and didn't think of that in relation to `clear`

Comment: Wow, not only is everything I ever wanted to do in a function but array dimensions are arbitrary. and the explanation is in plain english. You can't pay for help like that anymore.

Comment: @jamesson: You're welcome. And I hate to say this, because it feels like begging for points, but feel free to click the checkmark next to my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,1]];
alert(nums[0][0]); //1 
alert(nums[0][1]); //2
```

That's a two dimensional array. Loading data works just like with any other array.

To update it sequentially you are looking at queue behavior in javascript. Use unshift() and pop().

Javascript Arrays: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

Finally for averaging the columns assuming there are 10 positions:

```
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
    num1 +=array[i][0];
    num2 +=array[i][1];
}
num1 = num1/10;
num2 = num2/10;

//num1 is now the average of the first column
//num2 is now the average of the second column
```

Comment: Please don't feed W3Schools - use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead. See [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/) for the reasons :)